# Keep wildcards from resolving in a ksh script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am reading in a list of file names:

```
*.txt *.xml
```

which are space delimited. I read this into a variable in my ksh script, and I want to be able to manipulate it before putting each of them into a find command. The problem is, as soon as I do anything with the variable (for instance, breaking it into an array), the * resolves into filenames that are in my script's directory. What I want is for the *.txt to remain unchanged, so I can put that into my find command.

How do I do this? Unfortunately, I'm at work and can't just use perl or some other language.

Comment: Have you tried 'set noglob' or 'set -f'?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the * characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set -f

turns off globbing in ksh, so * and ? characters are not expanded (globbed).

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with

```
 '*.txt' '*.xml'
```

? . Else you have to show us more of your issues. Maybe edit your post to include a small test case that illustrates your problem, plus the desired output or intermediate values.